# How to set YouTube video as featured image?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails, post-meta, embed, youtube

I am trying to have all my posts with post_format set as video, have said video as the featured image. Here is what I am working with thus far but I need some help:

```
    if($post_format == 'video') {

    if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_site_url', true)) the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'video_site_url');        
        echo '<div class="video-containers single_item">'.wp_oembed_get(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_site_url', true)).'</div>';
}
```

Right now I'm using a YouTube's iframe to embed the video into my post and that seems to be working quite well.

Comment: Image is not a video. So technically "featured image" should be an "image". Try this [plugin](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/featured-video-plus/) if you want to get YouTube image and set it as featured image.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is not exactly a WordPress problem / solution.

First you have to either get the video id from the `video_site_url` post meta or save the YouTube video id in it's own post meta field, maybe `youtube_video_id`.

Next you can get the thumbnail using one of these url

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/0.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/1.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/2.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/3.jpg
```

[Read this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api)